# Pass a pointer to a property? fmdb and a custom class

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, I cannot even explain it right, but I will give it a shot,

I'm making a class that will create a FMDatabase as a property, and i want to open the db in the init method. It looks like this

```
FMDatabase *database = [[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:<insert path here>] retain];
[database open];
self.localData = *database;
```

i get an error assigning from imcompatible type.

is this even possible or am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: STUPID XCODE, i tried it like 10 times with out the * in front of database and it kept saying error, the second i post this, the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type does localData have? If its type is `FMDatabase*` (which it seems it should be) then assignment should look:

```
self.localData = database;
```

Comment: yea that was it, xcode lagged in removing the error the first time.

Comment: Ouch, I see you commented on that before my answer. sorry for being late :)